# What genes in a plant determine whether a stem is erect or climbing?

Tags: genetics, botany, plant-physiology

I was randomly reading this Wiki article on [Jasmine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmine) and this question crossed my mind after reading the following lines:

> Jasmine can be either deciduous (leaves falling in autumn) or evergreen (green all year round), and can be erect, spreading, or climbing shrubs and vines.

**How can a plant be both erect and climbing at the same time?**

I have looked for genetic mechanisms related to this, correlating environmental or other stimulus with this phenomenon, but have not found a satisfactory explanation.

**So how does this occur?**